# Programs for finding and installing drivers

Tags: drivers, installation

As a computer technician, I have to install os´s for many different computer machines. Sometimes when I have troubles finding the right driver for a board or system.

Can anyone think of a tool which can help you find the drivers for you and install them aswell?

I have tried Driver Checker, it does the job so now and then, mut mostly i finds drivers which are not 100% compatible, or just the wrong drivers for the hardware.

Someone told me that Driver Detective is a good one.

Can anyone think of a tool which is good, I know finding the drivers manually from the vendors website is the best way, but this takes too much time.

Comment: Not really answer to your question but perhaps a solution for your problem: http://driverpacks.net/

Comment: such a question is highly OS-dependent. On Linux, the answer is the installation program of a recently released distribution (any driver it doesn't have likely doesn't exist at production quality). But somehow I suspect this isn't the OS you had in mind; so *say which OS(es) you're targetting*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tool called drivermax that lets you take backup of all the drivers installed in your system. So, it will be very useful when reinstalling os in that system in future.

This is offtopic, but since you're a computer technician, I thought this might be useful.

Comment: it can be helpfull on a working computer indeed assuming it has correct installed drivers :) For crashed computers (defected harddisks ect) it's not usefull. +1

Comment: I have purchased the pro version, I hope this was a good choice, we'll see :) The pro version will also find/update drivers you need.

Comment: @Chris: Tell us if you find the find/update drivers feature is useful!

Comment: @ instantsetsuna, i will keep you updated

Comment: I have tested drivermax a few times and it does a much better job then driver detective or all those other driver find programs. Thumbs up!

Comment: Happy to hear that you found it useful! :)